# Qt qwt - error: 'QwtLog10ScaleEngine' does not name a type'

Tags: qt, mingw32, qwt

porting from Qt4.8, qwt6.0.2, VC++9.0 to Qt5.7, qwt6.1.3, Mingw5.3, I get the compiler error: 'QwtLog10ScaleEngine' does not name a type'

```
//SigLibGraph.cpp
void Plot2D::setXLogAxis()
{ 
setAxisScaleEngine( QwtPlot::xBottom, new QwtLog10ScaleEngine ); // error: 'QwtLog10ScaleEngine' does not name a type'
}

// SigLibGraph.h
class Plot2D: public QwtPlot
{ 
   Q_OBJECT 
public: 
   void setXLogAxis(); 
   ... 
};
```

What does the error message mean and how can I resolve the issue?

Thank you for your valuable time.
Alain

Comment: QwtLog10ScaleEngine does not exist: new QwtLogScaleEngine(10)

Comment: Is working, I thank you very much!